# IF(A1=TOMORROW(),

Tags: excel

How do I set one day before today; for example I would like a warning the day before a birthday..

```
=IF(C10=TODAY(),HYPERLINK("mailto:"&D10&"?subject="&$C$4&"&body="&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C$5,"$",B10),"@",$C$6),CHAR(10),"%0A"),"Send mail"),"")
```

Comment: Try `=IF(C10=TODAY()+1, ...`

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores dates as numbers. You can easily do simple maths with dates, like adding or subtracting days. A day is 1. Seven days is 7.

Today() is a function that returns the current date.  To get yesterday's date, subtract a day from Today() like `=Today()-1`. To get tomorrow's date add a day to Today() like `=Today()+1`.

This arithmetic can also be applied inside of more complex functions. The formula in your question looks at `Today()` and compares it to C10. If you want the same functionality if the date in C10 is "tomorrow", you nee to add a day to Today().

That's what Jeeped's comment means.

```
=IF(Today()+1=C10,[the rest of your formula]
```